# How to achieve a hover effect for an image button?

Tags: android-layout

How can I get an image button with hover effect? I have two button images one is simple and the other one is for the hover?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do it in CSS.

```
input[type='button']:hover
{
    color: #00a;
    //or background-image: url("url");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily with css by using a sprite image and moving the background image depending if its hovered or not.

css:

```
a { display:block; width: 80px; height: 40px; background: url(bgImage.png) top;
a:hover { background: url(bgImage.png) bottom; }
```

You have to combine your "simple" and "hover" image into a single image for this to work.

Comment: Oops, I thought he was talking about a navigation button, not input one. :)